# Problemas para Subir mi App error ITMS-90424: Invalid Swift Support

Tags: swift, xcode, certificado-apple, app-store

Estoy intentando subir mi aplicaron desde xcode version 11.3.1 estable y ellos me mandaron el siguiente correo:

Identificamos uno o más problemas con una entrega reciente de su aplicación. Corrija los siguientes problemas, luego cárguelos nuevamente.

> ITMS-90424: Soporte de Swift no válido: la carpeta SwiftSupport está
>   vacía. Reconstruya su aplicación utilizando la versión pública actual
>   (GM) de Xcode y vuelva a enviarla.

pero no dicen que específicamente necesita tener esa carpeta

Comment: Descargaste el Xcode del AppStore? Tienes esta versión 11.3.1 (11C504)?

Comment: si, descargue xcode del App Store